# Create donut chart using nested data from d3.nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created my nested data using d3.nest() and get `{"java":16,"other":17,"php":21,"py":17,"cpp":16,"js":13}`

I need to create a donut chart next...

I have created the outline for my donut chart but I have no idea how to read the above data and create a donut chart...

```
<pre>
       let data = [];

        // Fetch json data
    d3.json('/load_data', (d) => {

        return d;
    }).then((d) => {

            // Redefine data
         data = d['users'];

    let nested_data = d3.nest()
        .key((d)=>{return d.prog_lang;})
        .rollup((v)=> {
            return v.length;
        })
        .object(data);

        var jsonPie=JSON.stringify(nested_data);
        console.log(jsonPie);
    });
    var totals=[{
        title:"py",
        value:14,
        all: 100
        },
        {
        title: "java",
        value: 13,
        all: 100
        },
        {
        title:"php",
        value: 29,
        all:100
        },
        {
        title:"cpp",
        value:16,
        all:100
        },
        {
        title:"other",
        value: 15,
        all: 100
        },
        {
        title:"js",
        value:13,
        all:100
        }
    ];
    var width =300;
    var height=300;
    var radius=Math.min(width, height)/2;
    var donutWidth=50;
    var color=d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#1b7688","#1b7676","#f9d057","#f29e2e","9b0a0a","#d7191c"])
    var svg = d3.select('#donutChart')
         .append('svg')
         .attr('width', width)
         .attr('height', height)
         .append('g')
         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
    var arc = d3.arc()
         .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
         .outerRadius(radius);
    var pie = d3.pie()
         .value(function (d) {
              return d.value;
         })
         .sort(null);
    var path = svg.selectAll('path')
         .data(pie(totals))
         .enter()
         .append('path')
         .attr('d', arc)
         .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
              return color(d.data.title);
         })
         .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
</pre>
```

Ignore var totals as it is me manually writing the data... I have got the data from the nest and the output is shown above... I am really stuck (both my js and D3 skills are weak)...

I get a reference error when I replace totals with jsonPie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your source data, but if you use [`.entries`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nest_entries) instead of `.object` in your nest function you will get an array with the following format as the documentation says:

```
d3.entries({foo: 42, bar: true}); // [{key: "foo", value: 42}, {key: "bar", value: true}]
```

So your code will change from this:

```
let nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key((d)=>{return d.prog_lang;})
    .rollup((v)=> {
        return v.length;
    })
    .object(data);
```

To this:

```
let nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key((d)=>{return d.prog_lang;})
    .rollup((v)=> {
        return v.length;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

Then you can simply pass that array to the `pie`, like this:

```
svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(nested_data))
```